# how React function recognizes event without we passing it as an argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I started to learn React and I saw in one tutorial that the handler function understands that "event" is an synthetic event object wihtout we passing it inside of onChange like "{(e)=>handleChange(e)}". How function itself figures it out? What is the name of this concept? I would love to learn more about it. But I don't know what to search for. Thanks

`<input onChange={handleChange}/>`

`const handleChange = (event) => { console.log(event.target.value); }`

Comment: Whatever gets passed as onChange is called with a single argument, the event. That's it. No magic, React doesn't figure _anything_ out (nor does the function).

Comment: Your `handleChange` function is a *callback function*. That means that you pass the function as an argument. The callback function gets called whenever a `change` event happens and gets an `Event` object passed to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you please tell me what should I search to learn more about this topic? I don't know what to google. I only get irrelevant search results. Kindly tell me what concept this is please

Comment: It's just a function. When you call functions, you pass them arguments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but inside of onChange, it is not declared that event will be passed. still function understand that it should expect event type of object as parameter.

Comment: Why is `(e) => ...` if not a function that takes one argument? Why does that somehow "expect event type of object as parameter" any more or less than handleChange itself? There is no "inside of onChange"; you're just passing a function as the value of the prop.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe and @Emiel Zuurbier are spot on. But, I would like to explain it in a more simple way, so that a newbie can understand it better.

> What is the name of this concept? I would love to learn more about it. But I don't know what to search for.

I think that you have to read about callback functions in JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

> How function itself figures it out?

OnChange accepts a callback function. Did you think about the place that event come from? In order to understand that, let's assume that onChange is some function like this. (This is only an assumption to explain this for you). So, let's assume that the onChnage function does something to get the event and then calls the callback function you passed with the event as the first parameter.

```
function onChange(callback) {
  //does something to get the event
  const event = getEvent();

  //calling the callback function that you passed with the event
  callback(event);
}
```

So, now we know where the event comes from. So, you don't have to pass the event by yourself. The callback function you pass will be called with the event as the first parameter. I hope this is clear to you.